# Grails hibernate events are not firing during integration tests

Tags: hibernate, grails, integration-testing, grails-orm

During grails run-app hibernate events fire regularly without issue. However, during each integration test case these same events will not fire. Below is the essence of my code whittled down to its simplest form. Is hibernate even in use during integration testing? Is there a different testing method that can be applied? Suggestions or comments are most welcome.

The integration test

```
    @Mock ([User])
    class SomeIntegrationTests  {
         @Test
         void testSomething () {
               new User().save(flush: true)
         }

   }
```

The controller

```
    class Controller implements SaveOrUpdateEventListener {
        public void onSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event) throws HibernateException {
            print 'event fired'
        }
    }
```

resources.groovy

```
    beans = { service(MyService)

        hibernateEventListeners(HibernateEventListeners) {
           listenerMap=['save-update' : service, 'delete' : service]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mocking your `User` domain class.  When a domain class is mocked, hibernate isn't used.  If you remove `@Mock([User])` the real domain object will be used, including hibernate.

Comment: Ah. Now, as a follow up question, when the @Mock annotation is removed it seems as though grails cannot invoke dynamic finders (not included in my example above). Is there a way to use make a User.findAll() call without the mock tag?

Comment: Dynamic finders should work if the tests are located in the `test/integration` subdirectory.  This is the convention grails uses to indicate tests require the whole spring/hibernate stack.